# Php Wordpress campos personalizados - ordenar por data num query usando GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: php, wordpress

Boa tarde,

A minha pergunta é talvez complicada e se calhar é impossível fazer o que pretendo, desde já peço desculpa.

Estou a construir um website em Wordpress evitando recorrer a plugins, o que me trás aqui.

De modo a ter disponível uma agenda de eventos, onde às vezes o mesmo evento se repete em vários dias ou no mesmo dia a diferentes horas criei nos artigos um campo personalizado (dia|hora|local|quem|tipo), onde o utilizador coloca o dia, hora, local, quem e o tipo separados entre eles por "|", por exemplo "26/09/2020|16:00|parque desportivo|infantis masc|atl"

O que eu quero é selecionar da base de dados todos estes eventos para cada artigo, MAS ordena-los logo pela data de forma crescente

se usar

```
SELECT CONCAT(post_id) AS Post, GROUP_CONCAT(meta_value, '|sep|') AS Datas FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = '" . $id_do_post -> post_id . "' AND meta_key = 'dia|hora|local|quem|tipo' GROUP BY post_id
```

obtenho quase o que quero, mas os eventos aparecem por ordem de entrada

```
array (
0 => 
(object) array(
   'Post' => '2933',
   'Datas' => '26/09/2020|12:00|parque municipal|iniciados masc|atl|sep|,25/09/2020|14:00|parque municipal|infantis|atl|sep|,26/09/2020|18:00|centro de dia|seniores|universidade senior|sep|',
),
```

)

A pergunta é, existe alguma forma de fazer este query de modo a obter as datas ordenadas, 25/09 às 14h, depois o 26/09 às 12h e por fim o 26/09 às 18h?
E ainda outra questão, será igualmente possível determinar qual das datas é a mais próxima e adicionar ao array 'Mais_proxima' => '25/09/2020 ?

Desde já muito obrigado!